# Does Puppet 2.7 allow a class inheritance of an unparameterized "params" class?

Tags: puppet, dependencies, hiera

I'm getting the following error when I run `puppet-lint`:

```
$ puppet-lint manifests/*
manifests/init.pp - WARNING: class inheriting from params class on line 72
```

I had myself a quick search on duckduckgo.com, and got this:

http://puppet-lint.com/checks/class_inherits_from_params_class/

However, our Puppet Agent versions are all 2.7 or later, and our Puppet Masters are all 3.0 or later.

For reference, the `init.pp` code in question follows:

```
class myclass (
    $zone = 'top',
    $::myclass::params::base_url,
    $::myclass::params::username,
) inherits myclass::params {
...
```

The code in `params.pp` is as follows:

```
class myclass::params {
    $base_url  = hiera('myclass::base_url','https://beta.tpsreports.com/coversheets/')
    $username = hiera('clap::base_url','prod')
}
```

Even if the Hiera lookup fails, I still shouldn't be getting errors like this:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Must pass ::myclass::params::base_url to Class[Myclass] at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/beta_servers_0.pp:126 on node beta-web-server-0.tpsreports.com
```

Now that I've hashed through some of that background, to which I'm more than willing to add, if anyone asks, my questions follow:

1. If my `params` class will provide parameters even if the hiera lookup somehow fails, why am I getting this error?
2. Do I have to use the [horrible workaround (that is, "What you should have done" from the puppet-lint.com link,](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/class_inherits_from_params_class/) even though I have a Puppet version higher than `2.6.2` in all cases?

Comment: // , Maybe it's just a typo or something. Code on Fridays tends to have a bit less accuracy than usual...

Comment: // , And that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `init.pp` class should read:

```
class myclass (
    $zone = 'top',
    $base_url = $::myclass::params::base_url,
    $username = $::myclass::params::username,
) inherits myclass::params {
```

You don't directly put the inherited variables in your parameter list; you use them as the default values for this class's parameters.

Comment: // , Yes, I came to the same conclusion last night. This was the correct answer. Now my Hiera lookups fail. Though equally awkward, failing Hiera Data Lookups are a separate difficulty.